# Event listener for md-virtual-repeat element

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

guys, would be very grateful for advice I'm trying to implement Angular Material's Virtual Repeat with a custom directive for the list items, and I'm having issues binding directive functions md-repeat elements. 
I want to apply scrolling function for fixed table header for each md-virtual element (I have like 20-30 tables)

```
<section class="container-fluid" ng-cloak style="background: #ffffff;" >
  <md-virtual-repeat-container id="horizontal-container" style="height:830px;" >
    <div md-item-size="430"  my-post-repeat-directive   md-virtual-repeat="group in tasks.content" ng-cloak>
     <div class="wrap" style="margin-bottom: 15px;"  id="table_{{group.id}}"  >
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" ng-cloak>
        <thead >
          <tr>
           <th ng-repeat="name in tasks.headers.agents track by $index" ng-bind="name.title" ng-show="name.visible"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
          <tbody  >
         <tr style="height:54px" ng-repeat="agent in tasks.content[$index].agents track by $index" ng-click="showMenu($event, navigation)">
          <td ng-bind="agent.agt_id" style="font-weight:normal"></td>
          <td ng-bind="agent.agt_presence"  style="font-weight:normal"></td>
          <td ng-bind="agent.agt_call_direction"  style="font-weight:normal"></td>
          <td ng-bind="agent.agt_calls_total"  style="font-weight:normal"></td>
          <td ng-bind="agent.agt_calls_talk_time_avg"  style="font-weight:normal"></td>
          <td ng-bind="agent.agt_calls_talk_time_total"  style="font-weight:normal"></td>
          <td ng-bind="agent.agt_calls_hold_time_total"  style="font-weight:normal"></td>
        </tr>
           </tbody>
      </table>
                        </div>
```

Here is the directive

```
part1.directive('myPostRepeatDirective', function() {

 return function(scope, element, attrs,window) {

         let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('div.wrap')

         for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

             buttons[i].addEventListener("scroll", function () {
                 console.log('test scroll')
                 var translate = "translate(0," + (this.scrollTop - 1) + "px)";

                 this.querySelector("thead").style.background = 'white'

                 let x = this.querySelectorAll("thead th")
                 if (this.scrollTop > 0) {
                     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                         event.stopPropagation();
                         x[i].style.border = "1px solid #ddd";
                     }

                 } else {
                     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                         event.stopPropagation();
                         x[i].style.border = "";
                         var translate = "translate(0," + (this.scrollTop) + "px)"
                     }
                 }
                 this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
             })
         }
     }
})
```

The problem is that the event listener scrolling value sometimes stays the same when I scroll the virtual repeat container, for example I scroll the table body from the first md-repeat element, then i go down the the last md-repeat element and it has the same css translate value.. Looks like value is applied when new md-virutal repeat element is rendered.

Thank you in advance.